# Find usercontrol panel in parent page using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, findcontrol, user-controls

How can I find a panel defined in usercontrol from its parent page using jquery?

like the equivalent of
 document.getElementById('<%= UserControl.FindControl("pnlInputs").ClientID %>') in jquery

Comment: What you mean when you say parent page ? Is it a popup which you are referring as child page ? Or Masterpahe in ASP.NET which you are referring as parent page .

Comment: @Sonesh  parent page means aspx page using the the usercontrol containing the panel

Answer (score 2):

You are probably best off giving the control a unique CssClass attribute and selecting it with `$(".myParentPageControl")` instead of trying to retrieve the ClientID.

Answer (score 1):

Because .NET wants to control all of the IDs, you're better off assigning class names and using them instead.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking equivalent to JQuery . It will be $('#<%= UserControl.FindControl("pnlInputs").ClientID %>')

Additionally check this link http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2009/03/26/jquery-accessing-the-client-generated-id-of-aspnet-controls/